# font embedding in flash- query re external swfs

Tags: flash, fonts, embedding

I've embedded a font in a flash based website. The site loads external swfs which also contain content in that font. Can these external swfs make use of the font without it being embedded in them?

Comment: Is this a yes or no question? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, yes, I'd intended it to be a yes or no question, although any more info folk are willing to share would be appreciated!

Comment: Ok, then you need to supply more info: How do you embed the fonts? Is there a live example somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I'd embedded the font in the first instance by pressing the "embed" button in the flash text interface. My question is about whether, having embedded the font in the main swf, do i then need to embed it in external swfs that are loaded into the main swf separately. I struggle to get my head around fonts, not least because, obviously, they're installed in my own computer, so they will display correctly on testing whatever I do.... Thanks, again, for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it IT possible. I haven't done it myself, but here's a some info in the docs:

> The ISWFContext interface allows a SWF file to share its context with
>   other SWF files that load it. An application that loads a SWF file of
>   type ISWFContext can call methods in the context of the loaded SWF
>   file. The main usage is for calling the FTE TextLine creation methods.
>
> There are two reasons for an application to use this interface to
>   control TextLine creation:
>
> **Reuse an embedded font**: if an application wants to use a font embedded in a loaded SWF file, the application can access the font if
>   a TextLine is created in the context of the loaded SWF file.

From here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/compose/ISWFContext.html

It seems you make one SWF file, embed the font in that one, and reuse that SWF.

Comment: Thanks for your help! From my own research, I'd come to the conclusion the RunTime libraries were the way forward, another way to skin the cat?... wish me luck!